# jQuery Validation plugin grouping and asp.net

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am using jQuery Validation plugin.

I want to display only one error message for Date of birth, year and month. I am using groups for that. I am getting a reference error for TelephoneNumber, I think it is not recognizing the name attritbute like I have mentioned below. Please see the code below and advise if I am doing anything wrong.

```
 rulesObject[$("select[id$='ddlDOBDay']").attr('name')] = {
      required: true,
      valueNotEquals: "DFT"
  };
  rulesObject[$("select[id$='ddlDOBMonth']").attr('name')] = {
      required: true,
      valueNotEquals: "DFT"
  };
  rulesObject[$("select[id$='ddlDOBYear']").attr('name')] = {
      required: true,
      valueNotEquals: "DFT"
  };

          groups: {           
                TelephoneNumber: "$("select[id$='ddlTel2']").attr('name'), $("input[id$='txtTelephone2']").attr('name')"
           },
          errorPlacement: function(error, element) {                      
                if (element.attr("name") == $("select[id$='ddlTel2']").attr('name') || element.attr("name") == $("input[id$='txtTelephone2']").attr('name')) 
                error.insertAfter($("input[id$='txtTelephone2']"));
                else 
                error.insertAfter(element);
          },
```

Comment: can you provide a js fiddle.

Comment: Hi, I am getting error on this line...TelephoneNumber: "$("select[id$='ddlTel2']").attr('name'), $("input[id$='txtTelephone2']").attr('name')"

Comment: The [tag:jquery-validation-engine] is not the [tag:jquery-validate] plugin.  Please be more careful when tagging.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
TelephoneNumber: "$("select[id$='ddlTel2']").attr('name'), $("input[id$='txtTelephone2']").attr('name')"
```

is not valid JavaScript. You can see where SO's syntax highlighting breaks, this probably stops JavaScript from being executed at this point resulting in the error (just saw your comment).

Try

```
TelephoneNumber: $("select[id$='ddlTel2']").attr('name') + ', ' + ("input[id$='txtTelephone2']").attr('name')
```

This will produce the string that I *think* you want.

Comment: yes javascript is not able to split the 2 name attribute, since this is asp.net application I cannot get the name attribute directly, so I have used the above method, is there any easy way to get around this?

Comment: let me try your suggestion...just saw that after my post.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the many edits. I often use TAB because I'm used to that to indent my code, but on SO that focusses the "Add/Edit" button and when I hit enter... hehe